# VS 2019 custom code snippet with literals not expanding correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, code-snippets

I write a lot of configuration code. I built this snippet to make all of that repetitive code quicker to write. But it doesn't expand correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>New Configuration Property</Title>
            <Shortcut>newproperty</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Imports>
                <Import>
                    <Namespace>System.Configuration</Namespace>
                </Import>
            </Imports>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>$ConfigName$</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The name of the element property in the .config file</ToolTip>
                    <Default>configName</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>$PropertyName$</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The name of the class property</ToolTip>
                    <Default>PropertyName</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="CSharp" kind="" delimiter="$">
                <![CDATA[[ConfigurationProperty("$ConfigName$", IsRequired = true)]
public string $PropertyName$
{
    get { return (string)this["$ConfigName$"]; }
    set { this["$ConfigName$"] = value; }
}$selected$$end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

And this is what the output looks like.

```
        [ConfigurationProperty("", IsRequired = true)]
        public string 
{
    get { return (string) this[""]; }
        set { this[""] = value; }
}
```

There are no prompts for the literals. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it easy and simple by doing it like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
      <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
          <Title>New Configuration Property</Title>
          <Shortcut>newproperty</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
          <Imports>
            <Import>
              <Namespace>System.Configuration</Namespace>
            </Import>
          </Imports>
          <Declarations>
            <Literal>
              <ID>ConfigName</ID>
              <ToolTip>The name of the element property in the .config file</ToolTip>
              <Default>configName</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Literal>
              <ID>PropertyName</ID>
              <ToolTip>The name of the class property</ToolTip>
              <Default>PropertyName</Default>
            </Literal>
          </Declarations>
          <Code Language="csharp">
            <![CDATA[[ConfigurationProperty("$ConfigName$", IsRequired = true)]
    public string $PropertyName$
    {
        get { return (string)this["$ConfigName$"]; }
        set { this["$ConfigName$"] = value; }
    }
   $selected$ $end$]]>
          </Code>
        </Snippet>
      </CodeSnippet>
    </CodeSnippets>
```

You dont need the two parts = kind="" delimiter="$" and you dont need  to have dollar sign inside the ID, instead of doing: $ConfigName$ you can do: ConfigName Just look the above xml snippet, and the language should be good alternative if you wrote small letters like: csharp instead of Csharp or CSharp. I hope it will help you out,

Comment: Well that's embarrising. Thank you!